# Can a C# DLL/method get the public key of the currently executing assembly?

Tags: c#, cryptography

I have a C# executable assembly that I sign and I would like my DLLs to be able to verify that they are being called by my signed executable, and not rogue code.

Is there a way in C# to programmatically get the public key of the currently executing signed assembly, from inside a method that might be in a separate DLL?

Comment: Are you talking about Authenticode or Strong Naming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for:

```
byte[] key = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().GetPublicKey();
```